# C++ - Unexpected output from std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I'm writing a function which returns a string. But something weird happened. The output of the `result` string was printed as an unexpected thing from the console.

It becomes Chinese or something else or EMPTY STRING depending on the machine (**TESTED**). But this only happens when the input string is super long. It works normally for strings with a smaller size.

Is there a better way to append `char` to a string? It's because I suspect the problem was caused by the way how I added chars to the end of a string.

**From Console**

[image]

**From Debugger**

[image]

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool checkPalindrome(string s)
{
    return (s == std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend()));
}

string longestPalindrome(string s)
{
    if (s.size() > 1000 || s.empty())
        return "";

    string result = "";
    string sub = "";
    char* ptr = &sub[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        sub += s[i];
        while (true) {
            string temp = ptr;
            if (checkPalindrome(temp)) {
                ptr = &sub[0];
                if (temp.length() > result.length()) {
                    result = temp;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            else {
                ptr++;
            }
            if (ptr == &sub[sub.length()-1]) {
                ptr = &sub[0];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "end of function" << std::endl;
    return result;
}



int main()
{
    string output = longestPalindrome("babaddtattarrattatddetartrateedredividerb");
    std::cout << output << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile because `output` is a local variable in `main`, but you're somehow accessing it in `longestPalindrome`. Please post the actual, compiling code.

Comment: why not `for (auto character : s)`

Comment: @Blaze sorry about that. I just wanted to aovid using the same vairbale name then changed the local variable `output` to `result` in the function `longestPalindrome`.  I updated the post

Comment: `string sub = "";
    char* ptr = &sub[0];` Won't this cause UB?

Comment: `&sub[0]` on an empty string isn't UB: http://eel.is/c++draft/strings#string.access-1

Comment: @Barry I didn't know that. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Using an index and `substr` instead of a pointer would make you immune to reallocations.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I changed `string sub = ""` to `string sub = " "` with a white space. It still happend.

Comment: That sure is a lot of language tags. Seems like you could pick the one you're actually using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `char* ptr = &sub[0];` gives you a pointer to a `char`. However, when you perform `sub += s[i];` you may require the `string`'s internal storage to grow to accommodate the new character. If you keep adding to it, eventually it will happen. This will invalidate `ptr` and render it unusable until it's reassigned.

When such a reallocation does happen a larger buffer is allocated, the previous value is moved from the shorter buffer to the larger buffer then the shorter buffer is destroyed to be replaced by the larger one. But `ptr` still points to where the previous shorter buffer's data used to be. It's now pointing to an element of a destroyed object. When you then do `string temp = ptr;` you risk initializing a `string` from an invalidated pointer which is undefined behavior.

One relatively simple solution woult be to stick with indices instead of pointers. Indices by their nature don't get invalidated as long as they are within the bounds of the `string`'s size. Another possible solution might be to use `reserve` to pre-allocate a large enough capacity that it never has to reallocate.